# Error message Trying to get property of non-object whentrying to display results from a query

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm using a simple form to run a database query on a table in my database.  The connection doesn't appear to be a problem. The form renders without any issue.  When I go to the page though, I receive an error stating that I'm trying to get the property of a non object.  Here's the particular line being called out:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0){
    echo "$result";
}
```

Any ideas why?

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "oldga740_SeniorProject";


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$result= '';
//collect 
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
  $searchq = $_POST['search'];
  $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Client LIKE '%$searchq%'";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
}

//Display results
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "$result";

}

else {
     echo "0 results";
}


?>

<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

<form action="Index.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search...." />
  <input type="submit" value=">>" />
</form>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly straight forward. I have noted for clarity:

```
// You make it a variable here, with the assumption
// $_POST['search'] will transform it into an object later
$result= '';
// If there is a search variable try to search database
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Client LIKE '%$searchq%'";

    // All is good if the condition is met
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    // This has to go here because you have turned $result into an object now
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // Likely you will draw an error here, this is probably an array
        // that you will need to iterate over using while()
        echo "$result";
    }
}

/*
// If you leave it here, if the search is not being done, you've
// assigned $result = '' so you are doing ->num_rows on empty
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "$result";

}
*/
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following what you're saying.  Are you suggesting I use a while loop instead of the if statement?

Comment: Well first you have to relocate that `if` statement then you can see what the `$result` returns at that point.

Comment: I'm learning this as I go for a class, so I'm not as versed in php/mysqli as I probably should be.  I'm not sure where I would relocate it to.

Comment: What I have above in my example is where it should be located to. All the grayed out stuff can be deleted.

Comment: replace that portion with mine

Comment: Hold on, let me investigate. I use PDO so I have to look at then nanual

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95810/discussion-between-tony-and-rasclatt).